# Direct web users according to their geo locations

Tags: webserver, website, web, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

I plan to host a web site, but problem is that different courntries may have varied speed accessing website hosted in north america, for example, China.

therefore, i want to find a solution that host one website with different locations( maybe in asian zone, eurpean zone, north american zone) and when users access website, they will be directed to closest website server so the speed is guaranteed.

Anyone knows whats best way of doing it? any existing comercial solution ?

many thanks

Comment: Which web serving technology are you using? Apache, nginx or IIS?

Answer (score 0):

There is so much that could be stated here, having geographical DNS entries for location is a good option - but I really think you need to read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325523/load-balancing-based-on-proximity). In short I believe there is a *master DNS server* for a location where the local DNS servers (generally your ISP) update from; not to mention in some situations you can have multiple IP's against a record.

Let's say your DNS is with Digital Ocean; you could have the following:

www.exampledomain.org

138.128.5.69 #Japan

147.158.168.36 #Australia

Employing some third party product (possibly also provided by your website host or DNS provider) when the client asks for the host when looking up a URL it replies with the lowest latency.

I know this is poorly worded, and I will **hope** that other users will both correct me and improve the answer.

---

As for obtaining Global Load balancing I will add two examples:

I am in no way affiliated with Incapsula, but you can look at their [Global Load Balancing product here](https://www.incapsula.com/load-balancing/global-server-load-balancing-gslb.html) or even this [product](https://kemptechnologies.com/au/server-load-balancing-appliances/geo-loadmaster/).

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange itself uses [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com)
You'd think that would be recommendation enough ;-)